# Python add in data into array

Tags: python, arrays

I have rating and names array from user. But in the rating and names array, the user does not complete all the rating in place_name list. So I would like to add in the missing rating with 0, how can I do that? The expected result is as below.

rate from user

```
rating
[['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2']]

names
[['place a', 'place b', 'place c'],['place d', 'place e']]
```

place_name

```
   place name
0  place a 
1  place b
2  place c
3  place d
4  place e
```

expected result

```
[['1','2','3','0','0'], ['0','0','0','1','2']]
```

current code

```
userrating = np.zeros(len(place_name))
for counter in range(len(names)):
  indices = place_name[place_name.isin(names[counter])].index
  userrating[indices] = ratings[counter]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your name rating to ratings for a better understanding.

```
names = [['place a', 'place b', 'place c'], ['place d', 'place e']]
ratings = [['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2']]
ref_names = ['place a', 'place b', 'place c', 'place d', 'place e']

 my_final_list = list()
 for name, rating in zip(names, ratings):
    list_indexes = [ref_names.index(x) for x in name]
    ref_values = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    for count, idx in enumerate(list_indexes):
        ref_values[idx] = rating[count]
    my_final_list.append(ref_values)
```

Comment: The error shows that  "TypeError: 'RangeIndex' object is not callable"

Comment: sorry I forgot to put the reference list of names. Should work now